# Integrating deltaspike with vraptor

Tags: cdi, deltaspike, vraptor

I have one project work with Vraptor 4 and i want to use deltaspike jpa and data modules to perform some operations. I need to deploy the application in tomcat 7+.
Is it possible to integrate vraptor with deltaspike ?

Also i do not want to use vraptor-jpa or vraptor-hibernate plugin.

Comment: should be - they are all CDI extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, i don't know in TomCat but i use it with Wildfly and works just fine, the only must is to use VRaptor 4, i already tested the following modules with success:

- Core
- Bean Validation
- Data
- JPA
- Servlet
- Test-Control
- Security

In their site it all the docs you need.

[Delta Skipike Documentation](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/modules.html)

The exemples below isn't using VRaptor, but can be applied since its CDI extension.

[Examples](https://github.com/rsmeral/deltaspike-examples)